# EPPlus removing milliseconds when reading cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I am attempting to read timestamps out of an excel sheet, which go down to a millisecond level.
e.g. **00:00:15.480**, **00:00:24.640**
However when i read the text value of the cell, it is rounding to the nearest second.

```
var ts = sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2].Text; /* would produce 00:00:15.000 and 00:00:25.000 in above examples */
```

I have tried setting the number format on the cells to the be same custom format referenced in the sheet itself, but this has no effect:

```
sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm:ss.000";
```

If I try to access the value directly with

```
var ts = sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2].Value;
```

it returns a double, e.g. 2.9166666666666666E-05

How can I get the timestamps with their millisecond values? Does EPPlus simply not allow this level of granularity?

Comment: update the column data type on your import

Comment: Please can you provide a little more detail on your suggestion? I can't see anything in EPPlus to facilitate that.

Comment: if the excel sheet column type is not accurate you loose the value, try DateTime.ToOADate() or MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff

Comment: .fff instead of .000 worked. Thank you.

Comment: @ Mark Seymour, mark the question as answered so that the rest of the community knows

Answer (score 0):

As per Walter Vehoeven's comment, my issue was the format should have been "hh:mm:ss.fff"